# A function to get the absolute position for a chutes and ladders game?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div that holds the image of a 100x100 grid, and it's set to relative

```
<div className="relative">
    <img src={tile_img} alt="tile" className="h-full" />
    // player piece
</div>
```

The piece will then have an absolute value like this

```
// Position at tile 1
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5%; left: 5%"></div>

// Position at tile 10
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5%; left: 95%"></div>

// Position at tile 11
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 15%; left: 95%"></div>

// Position at tile 12
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 15%; left: 85%"></div>
```

I've been thinking on making a function which does not involve rendering the Tiles individually as an object, but rather to just return the absolute position relative to the parent `div`. I can determine the vertical positions but having a hard time figuring out the horizontal positions, as the direction changes from right-to-left to left-to-right when changing rows.

Here's what I have

```
function moveTo(tile) {
    // I'm thinking of maybe initially getting the direction based on the modulus? Then what
    let dir = tile % 20 
    let x = // How do I get this
    let y = Math.floor(tile / 10) * 10 + 5
    return [x, y]
}
```

Heres a picture to visualize it better (cropped)(assume image size is a perfect square):
[image: piece-movement]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure to understand what is the motion you try to replicate ?

Comment: @NicolasJulémont In chutes and ladders, from tile 1 to 10 you would only have to change the horizontal positions, then when changing from 10 to 11, you would only have to move vertically and change the horizontal positions to be left-to-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the 'tens' and the 'ones', i.e. 74 is made up of 7x10+4x1.

The piece moves from left to right when the 'tens' are even (0x, 2x, 4x, etc.) and right to left when its odd (1x, 3x, 5x).

The following function converts the movement into relative distance based on the board you've provided, i.e. tile 1 at x=0.5, y=0.5; tile 2 at x=1.5, y=0.5; tile 11 at x=1.5, y=1.5 etc, where the distance between tiles is increments of 1.

```
function convertDistance(tile){

  console.log(`Start tile ${tile}`)

  // Convert tile to relative distance e.g. 
  // Case A. tile = 46, x=6+0.5=6.5, y=4+0.5=4.5
  // Case B. tile = 33, x=10-(3+0.5)=6.5, y =3+0.5

  // shift tile back by -1
  tile-=1;

  // Find ones and tens
  let ones = tile % 10;
  let tens = Math.floor(tile / 10);

  //Now check if tens is even or odd; if even use case A, odd use case B 
  let x_rel = tens % 2 == 0 ? ones+0.5 : 10-(ones+0.5);
  let y_rel = tens+0.5

  console.log(`Relative tile distance; x_rel = ${x_rel}, y_rel = ${y_rel}`)

}

//Test from tile 1 to tile 100
for (let i=1; i<101; i++){
    convertDistance(i)
}
```

The output will then give you the x-y relative distances from tiles 1 to 100.